# How to reset smart data?

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive, data-recovery

I have a drive that used to have reallocated sectors, until I deleted any data on the affected area and partitioned around it. It works fine, and has worked fine for over a year, I just want to know how I can reset the smart data, as the reallocated sector count has gone back down to 0, I need to reset smart or something so that I can install windows, as windows 7 does not allow installation on "failing" media. Any ideas, or any workarounds are appreciated.

Comment: I fail to see how this question is related to Ubuntu.

Comment: I really don't know where else it would be good to ask, but the thing is, I need to fix it with ubuntu specifically as I can't install any other non-linux operating system. Basically I want to use UBUNTU to erase the smart data of a disk with UBUNTU on it

Comment: See http://askubuntu.com/questions/342976/how-to-reset-smart-results then. The question is mostly about HDD temp, but the answers apply to your question too.