# Is this error ever can be solved?

Tags: hard-drive

Having trouble to boot as bios and format my hard as MBR ( even GPT is not working )
here is a screenshot for further details

[image]

and when I ran `smartctl -a /dev/sda` 
I get the following output

```
 === START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Model Family:     Seagate Samsung SpinPoint M8 (AF)
Device Model:     ST750LM022 HN-M750MBB
Serial Number:    S2RRJ9BD306196
LU WWN Device Id: 5 0004cf 209eebf94
Firmware Version: 2AR10002
User Capacity:    750,156,374,016 bytes [750 GB]
Sector Sizes:     512 bytes logical, 4096 bytes physical
Rotation Rate:    5400 rpm
Form Factor:      2.5 inches
Device is:        In smartctl database [for details use: -P show]
ATA Version is:   ATA8-ACS T13/1699-D revision 6
SATA Version is:  SATA 3.0, 3.0 Gb/s (current: 3.0 Gb/s)
Local Time is:    Mon Oct  2 19:34:45 2017 EET
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED

General SMART Values:
Offline data collection status:  (0x00) Offline data collection activity
                    was never started.
                    Auto Offline Data Collection: Disabled.
Self-test execution status:      ( 121) The previous self-test completed having
                    the read element of the test failed.
Total time to complete Offline 
data collection:        (10140) seconds.
Offline data collection
capabilities:            (0x5b) SMART execute Offline immediate.
                    Auto Offline data collection on/off support.
                    Suspend Offline collection upon new
                    command.
                    Offline surface scan supported.
                    Self-test supported.
                    No Conveyance Self-test supported.
                    Selective Self-test supported.
SMART capabilities:            (0x0003) Saves SMART data before entering
                    power-saving mode.
                    Supports SMART auto save timer.
Error logging capability:        (0x01) Error logging supported.
                    General Purpose Logging supported.
Short self-test routine 
recommended polling time:    (   2) minutes.
Extended self-test routine
recommended polling time:    ( 169) minutes.
SCT capabilities:          (0x003f) SCT Status supported.
                    SCT Error Recovery Control supported.
                    SCT Feature Control supported.
                    SCT Data Table supported.

SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 16
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     0x002f   100   100   051    Pre-fail  Always       -       28010
  2 Throughput_Performance  0x0026   252   252   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
  3 Spin_Up_Time            0x0023   089   059   025    Pre-fail  Always       -       3463
  4 Start_Stop_Count        0x0032   097   097   000    Old_age   Always       -       3780
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0033   252   252   010    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  7 Seek_Error_Rate         0x002e   252   252   051    Old_age   Always       -       0
  8 Seek_Time_Performance   0x0024   252   252   015    Old_age   Offline      -       0
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       12630
 10 Spin_Retry_Count        0x0032   252   252   051    Old_age   Always       -       0
 11 Calibration_Retry_Count 0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       260
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   097   097   000    Old_age   Always       -       3356
191 G-Sense_Error_Rate      0x0022   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       804
192 Power-Off_Retract_Count 0x0022   252   252   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0002   060   041   000    Old_age   Always       -       40 (Min/Max 15/59)
195 Hardware_ECC_Recovered  0x003a   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
196 Reallocated_Event_Count 0x0032   252   252   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
197 Current_Pending_Sector  0x0032   100   099   000    Old_age   Always       -       3
198 Offline_Uncorrectable   0x0030   252   252   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    0x0036   098   098   000    Old_age   Always       -       1404
200 Multi_Zone_Error_Rate   0x002a   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       2133
223 Load_Retry_Count        0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       260
225 Load_Cycle_Count        0x0032   088   088   000    Old_age   Always       -       128226

SMART Error Log Version: 1
ATA Error Count: 277 (device log contains only the most recent five errors)
    CR = Command Register [HEX]
    FR = Features Register [HEX]
    SC = Sector Count Register [HEX]
    SN = Sector Number Register [HEX]
    CL = Cylinder Low Register [HEX]
    CH = Cylinder High Register [HEX]
    DH = Device/Head Register [HEX]
    DC = Device Command Register [HEX]
    ER = Error register [HEX]
    ST = Status register [HEX]
Powered_Up_Time is measured from power on, and printed as
DDd+hh:mm:SS.sss where DD=days, hh=hours, mm=minutes,
SS=sec, and sss=millisec. It "wraps" after 49.710 days.

Error 277 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 12509 hours (521 days + 5 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  84 51 00 00 4f c2 a0  Error: ABRT

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  b0 d0 00 00 4f c2 a0 00      00:00:00.008  SMART READ DATA
  b0 d0 00 00 4f c2 a0 00      00:00:00.008  SMART READ DATA
  b0 d8 00 00 4f c2 a0 00      00:00:00.008  SMART ENABLE OPERATIONS
  f8 00 00 00 00 00 e0 00      00:00:00.008  READ NATIVE MAX ADDRESS [OBS-ACS-3]
  ec 00 00 00 00 00 a0 00      00:00:00.006  IDENTIFY DEVICE

Error 276 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 12509 hours (521 days + 5 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  84 51 00 00 00 00 a0

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  ec 00 00 00 00 00 a0 00      00:00:00.006  IDENTIFY DEVICE

Error 275 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 12509 hours (521 days + 5 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  84 51 00 00 4f c2 a0  Error: ABRT

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  b0 d1 00 00 4f c2 a0 00      00:00:00.018  SMART READ ATTRIBUTE THRESHOLDS [OBS-4]
  b0 d0 00 00 4f c2 a0 00      00:00:00.018  SMART READ DATA
  b0 d8 00 00 4f c2 a0 00      00:00:00.018  SMART ENABLE OPERATIONS
  27 00 00 00 00 00 e0 00      00:00:00.018  READ NATIVE MAX ADDRESS EXT [OBS-ACS-3]
  ec 00 00 00 00 00 a0 00      00:00:00.015  IDENTIFY DEVICE

Error 274 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 12291 hours (512 days + 3 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  40 51 08 20 a7 58 ed  Error: UNC 8 sectors at LBA = 0x0d58a720 = 223913760

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  c8 00 08 20 a7 58 ed 00      00:00:54.028  READ DMA
  ca 00 08 70 21 46 e9 00      00:00:54.028  WRITE DMA
  ea 00 00 00 00 00 e0 00      00:00:54.028  FLUSH CACHE EXT
  ca 00 38 38 21 46 e9 00      00:00:54.028  WRITE DMA
  ef 10 02 00 00 00 a0 00      00:00:54.028  SET FEATURES [Enable SATA feature]

Error 273 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 12291 hours (512 days + 3 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  40 51 08 20 a7 58 ed  Error: UNC 8 sectors at LBA = 0x0d58a720 = 223913760

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  c8 00 08 20 a7 58 ed 00      00:00:54.026  READ DMA
  c8 00 08 18 a7 58 ed 00      00:00:54.026  READ DMA
  c8 00 08 10 a7 58 ed 00      00:00:54.026  READ DMA
  c8 00 08 08 a7 58 ed 00      00:00:54.026  READ DMA
  c8 00 08 00 a7 58 ed 00      00:00:54.026  READ DMA

SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
Num  Test_Description    Status                  Remaining  LifeTime(hours)  LBA_of_first_error
# 1  Short offline       Completed: read failure       90%     12630         1465144320
# 2  Extended offline    Aborted by host               60%     12630         -
# 3  Short offline       Completed: read failure       90%     12629         1465144320
# 4  Extended offline    Aborted by host               90%     12629         -
# 5  Short offline       Completed: read failure       90%     12628         1465144320
# 6  Extended offline    Aborted by host               90%     12628         -
# 7  Short offline       Completed: read failure       90%     12628         1465144320
# 8  Short offline       Completed: read failure       90%     12628         1465144320
# 9  Extended offline    Interrupted (host reset)      90%     12510         -
#10  Short offline       Completed: read failure       90%     12510         1465144320
#11  Extended offline    Aborted by host               70%     12484         -
#12  Short offline       Completed: read failure       90%     12483         1139114040
#13  Extended offline    Aborted by host               90%     12384         -
#14  Short offline       Completed: read failure       90%     12384         1465147904
#15  Short offline       Completed: read failure       90%     12384         1465147904
#16  Short offline       Completed: read failure       90%     12381         310080928
#17  Short offline       Completed: read failure       90%     12381         310080928

SMART Selective self-test log data structure revision number 0
Note: revision number not 1 implies that no selective self-test has ever been run
 SPAN  MIN_LBA  MAX_LBA  CURRENT_TEST_STATUS
    1        0        0  Completed_read_failure [90% left] (0-65535)
    2        0        0  Not_testing
    3        0        0  Not_testing
    4        0        0  Not_testing
    5        0        0  Not_testing
Selective self-test flags (0x0):
  After scanning selected spans, do NOT read-scan remainder of disk.
If Selective self-test is pending on power-up, resume after 0 minute 
delay.
```

I also get the same error as in [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/133946/are-these-sata-errors-dangerous) on boot up

can someone help? can't find any solution anywhere

Comment: You have 277 errors listed there.  There might be a chance that your hard drive might be dying.  I am not aware of being able to reset SMART errors through software, but you can take a look at this:  https://askubuntu.com/questions/342976/how-to-reset-smart-results

Comment: Sounds like a bad hard disk. If you can, I'd backup any important files, run the Seagate diagnostic application, and possibly replace the drive.

Comment: I went to the technicians last night to check about the drive and they all said it's good and healthy so they recommended it might be a software problem

Comment: The "technicians" are wrong. Perhaps if you consulted with engineers the report would be different like, for instance, a "self-test failed" is pretty much conclusive.

Comment: @MichaelBay what do you suggest? try another HDD? some suggested that I change the data cable but I just got into  the mother board an hour ago to check for myself and saw my HDD attached to the socket and the socket is in the board itself so I don't think that's replaceable ( pardon my hardware understanding not a big fan)

Comment: Yes, try another HDD.

Comment: Sorry for the delay but I had some real issues but Huraay! you were right guys the problem was with the HDD so please write that in an answer so we can mark that as solved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The HDD was failing as said in the above comments